# Staging instance on Heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku, staging

I'd like to be able to push code to `dev.myapp.com` for testing and then to `www.myapp.com` for production use. Is this possible with Heroku?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Your interface to Heroku is essentially a Git branch. The Heroku gem does some work through their API, but within your Git repository, it's just a new remote branch.

```
heroku create yourapp # production
git br -D heroku # delete the default branch

heroku create staging-yourapp # staging
git br -D heroku # delete the default branch
```

Once you set up multiple applications on Heroku, you should be able to configure your Git repository like this:

```
git remote add staging git@heroku.com:staging-yourapp.git
git push origin staging

git remote add production git@heroku.com:yourapp.git
git push origin production
```

I usually work in a 'working' branch, and use Github for my master.

Assuming that's the case for you, your deploy workflow would probably look something like:

```
git co -b working
# do some work

# push to github:
git co master
git merge working
git push

# push to staging:
git co staging
git merge master
git push origin staging

# push to production
git co production
git merge master
git push origin production
```

Comment: Thanks -- this makes some sense (I suck at git). Question: Suppose I'm working on some cutting-edge changes on branch "edge". How can I push that branch to staging-myapp without affecting myapp (which currently is running on the master branch)? Does `git push staging edge work`?

Comment: In the interest of getting you going, you would just merge edge to your staging branch and push it. Your production branch is separate and clean. You can always branch it and make changes that only merge back there.

Comment: Instead of creating apps with the default 'heroku' remote branch and after deleting it, you can use a much nicer solution like: `heroku create yourapp --remote your-remote`

Comment: That sounds great to me, I don't have time to confirm right now. If you can edit the answer to reflect this information, please do!

Comment: Once you set this up, all your `heroku` commands need to include `--app staging` or `--app production`. Is there any way to set a default? (Asking as a comment b/c this seems too targeted to be a full-fledged SO question.)

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth To set a default Heroku app, use something like "git config heroku.remote staging".  More in the Heroku docs at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments.

Comment: @HoraceLoeb- Answer to your original comment: `git push staging edge:master`

Comment: Since Heroku is pulling from `staging` and `production`, what purpose does the `master` branch serve? Couldn't you simplify and make `master` the home for the production code?

Comment: The sample workflow seems misleading – AFAICT you're not pushing to GitHub, the staging server, and the production server; you're pushing to the `master` branch on GitHub, the `staging` branch on GitHub, and the `production` branch on GitHub.

Comment: Hey @Zach - The lines above where you see, "git remote add" actually update the .git/config file and create a connection between those local branches and the non-Github remote targets.

Comment: It was so easy. Thank you

Answer (score 19):

This explains everything you need to know if your a newbie like me: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Answer (score 10):

A key part of the original question is about linking up the staging app to a subdomain (dev.myapp.com) of the main app (www.myapp.com).  This hasn't been addressed in any of the answers.

Step 1: Configure both production ('myapp') and staging ('staging-myapp') versions of your app as is indicated in the answer by Luke Bayes

Step 2: In your domain management system (e.g. GoDaddy):

```
Create a CNAME record:  dev.myapp.com 
that points to:   proxy.heroku.com
```

Step 3: Configure Heroku to route dev.myapp.com to staging-myapp:

```
heroku domains:add dev.myapp.com --app staging-myapp
```

After the CNAME record has had time to propagate, you will be able to run your staging app at dev.myapp.com.

Comment: how about access control so it doesn't show up in google etc. and people don't stumble upon it and think its the real thing? any nice solutions?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way is to skip the GoDaddy step and access the "dev" version of your app directly off the Heroku domain using the Heroku URL.  (e.g. http://stormy-lake-5483.heroku.com.)  However, if you want to have 'dev' off your domain as described here, you can always install a robots.txt file to tell google, bing, et. al. to not index your dev site.  That will help keep it out of the search engines.

Comment: I ended up adding a `before_filter` hook to my `application_controller` to catch EVERYTHING in staging and force the user to login as an admin, then set an admin cookie so I can still see the app from the point of view of a 'non-admin'. Working pretty good for me.

Answer (score 8):

You should check the [heroku_san](https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san)

It does a pretty good job juggling with environments on heroku.

Answer (score 7):

Things are easier now. Here's how you do it...

### Create an app for each environment

```
$ heroku create myapp --remote production
$ heroku create myapp-staging --remote staging
```

This will create named remote repos for each app, which you can see in `.git/config`.

You can now use either the **--app** or **--remote** switches to target a particular app:

```
$ heroku info --app myapp-staging
$ heroku info --remote staging
```

### Set Rails environments

For Rails apps, Heroku [defaults to the "production" environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rails-4-x-applications). If you want your staging app to run in a staging environment, [create the environment](http://railscasts.com/episodes/72-adding-an-environment-revised) in your project and set the corresponding **RAILS_ENV** and **RAKE_ENV** environment variables on the app:

```
$ heroku config:set RACK_ENV=staging RAILS_ENV=staging --remote staging
```

### Configure environments

If you have other configuration variables you'll need to pass them in for each environment as well.

```
$ heroku config:set AWS_KEY=abc --remote staging
$ heroku config:set AWD_SECRET=123 --remote staging
...etc
```

That's a huge pain though so I just use my [**snappconfig**](https://github.com/ykessler/snappconfig#snappconfig) gem and run

```
$ rake heroku:config:load[myapp-staging]
```

to load my project's YAML config files into Heroku.

### Deploy

Now you just push to Heroku like this:

```
$ git push staging master
$ git push production master
```

and migrate like this:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --remote production
```

---

(See [Managing Multiple Environments for an App | Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) for more info and shortcuts.)

Comment: Setting `RAILS_ENV` and `RACK_ENV` to `staging` is discouraged by Heroku: "It may be tempting to create another custom environment such as “staging” and create a config/environments/staging.rb and deploy to a Heroku app with RAILS_ENV=staging. This is not a good practice. Instead we recommend always running in production mode and modifying any behavior by setting your config vars." More on this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-to-a-custom-rails-environment

Comment: @Koen- Trying to manage complex Rails configurations without the context of environments is totally impractical in my experience, whether on Heroku or otherwise. If you have a whole set of connection strings, API keys, etc for your staging app and another for your production app, are you really gonna set those config vars individually for each? That's just asking for trouble- Heroku is giving bad advice here.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for staging that really get a real URL, probably with commithash. I think this is something that Zeit Now or Netlify made it easy.