# Carrierwave storage path management with a staging instance on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave, staging

I have two instances of my app in production on Heroku, `staging.myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com`, and I am following this workflow: [Staging instance on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279787/staging-instance-on-heroku).
As I am using Carrierwave with AWS S3, I would like to know if it is possible to modify the storage path in order to specify each instance, e.g.:

```
def store_dir
  instance = "staging" | "production"       
  #{instance}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep my assets in seperate buckets and do it like this;

```
config.fog_directory  = "myappname-#{Rails.env}-assets"
```

so it will use a bucket name myappname-production-assets or myappname-staging-assets.

in my carrierwave initializer. Make sure you read 'Configuring Carrierwave' on https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave and 'Using Amazon S3'

Comment: Ok but how do you get `Rails.env` to `"staging"`? I have the 2 different environments on Heroku but both show `Rails.env = "production"`

Comment: heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging RAILS_ENV=staging