# How to deploy stage server in Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, staging

My Rails app is hosted on Heroku. I would like to have another server for staging (i.e., showing and testing new features) before updating my main app.

I have no idea how to do this in general, and in Rails.

How should I go about it? Do I need to create entirely new app, Git repository, Heroku server etc.?

What would be the most popular Gem for this kind of job? (I hear a lot about Caspitrano, but I don't know how it helps in context of Heroku).

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19052416/165673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku documentation is covered this case. You just need create another branch for staging.
Check it https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments